# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Spree::CheckoutController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, e-commerce, spree

After installing spree stable 2.0 version ...
with the sample -products 
i am trying to see the way spree works 
but on the checkout (step 2:: url ::- /checkout/delivery ) ..
it seems to be giving me error like..
----second step of checkout process --(after clicking on save& continue)

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Spree::CheckoutController#update
>
> Couldn't find Spree::Shipment with ID=45 for Spree::Order with ID=6
>   ----------stack trace... activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:463:in
>   raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found' activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:428:inblock in
>   assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association' activerecord
>   (3.2.13) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:401:in each'
>   activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:401:inassign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
>   activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:289:in
>   shipments_attributes=' activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:94:inblock in
>   assign_attributes' activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in each' activerecord
>   (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:inassign_attributes'
>   activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:216:in block in
>   update_attributes' activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:inblock in
>   with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in
>   transaction' activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:intransaction' activerecord
>   (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in
>   with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:inupdate_attributes'
>   /home/sanjeev.kumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bundler/gems/spree-562f390cbacf/frontend/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb:25:in
>   `update'